# How to handle form validation on mapped fields with React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I wish to generate multiple form fields from an array of objects, utilizing React Hook Forms Controller component to provide validation, rendering a Material UI TextField component.

I have managed to generate the fields with their unique values but cannot work out how to get the validation to work on a per field basis.

Below you can see what I have tried, this renders each items 'name, quantity, price and total' fields correctly and will prevent the form from submitting if any of these fields are left blank. However if any of these fields are left blank, every item field will show an error state, whereas I wish to have the error state be localized to that specific field.

I have omitted much of my code for the sake of brevity, but please do let me know if I have missed some crucial information here.

Many thanks for your time.
Glen

```
interface IItem {
  name: string
  quantity: number
  price: number
  total: number
}

interface IFormInput {
  name: string
  email: string
  items: IItem[]
}

const { control, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm<IFormInput>()

const handleFormSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = (data) => {
  console.log(data)
}

const data = {
  name: 'john doe',
  email: 'johndoe@mail.com',
  items: [
    { name: 'Banner Design', quantity: 1, price: 150, total: 150 },
    { name: 'Email Design', quantity: 2, price: 200, total: 400 },
  ],
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(handleFormSubmit)}>
    ...data.name controller
    ...data.email controller

    {data.items.map((item, index) => (
      <Controller
        name={`items.${index}.name`}
        control={control}
        defaultValue={item.name}
        rules={{
          required: "can't be empty",
        }}
        render={({ field }) => (
          /* cannot access errors.items.${index}.name here  */
          <FormControl error={!!errors.items}>
            <InputLabel>Item Name</InputLabel>
            <TextField {...field} />
          </FormControl>
        )}
      />

      ...item.quantity controller
      ...item.price controller
      ...item.total controller

    )}

    <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>

  </form>
)
```